# URL is changed when using new {@class = "btn btn-primary"}

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I created an Actionlink like so:

```
Html.ActionLink("SignUp","SignUp","Account", new { @class="btn btn-primary"})
```

It's supposed to bring me to the "SignUp" method in the "Account" controller and the URL should be like so:

```
http://localhost:23181/Account/SignUp
```

but what I get is this URL

```
http://localhost:23181/Home/SignUp?Length=7
```

If I remove the `new { @class="btn btn-primary"}`, I get the correct URL.
Can you please show me what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because MVC tries to serialize the object,

You can try passing null to the `routeValues` parameter

```
Html.ActionLink("SignUp","SignUp","Account",null, new { @class="btn btn-primary"})
```

Here is the ActionLink extension from MSDN:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Thank you! I just need to wait for 7 minutes to mark this as answered. It's required.

Comment: Awesome, glad that helps.